# How should I use the integral in this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's say there is a charged tube(cylinder with no top or bottom) with radius $a$, length $l$ and charge $q$ and a point which is collinear with the centre of the charged tube. Anyway, since we can think the tube as infinite charged rings we first should calculate the electric field of a single ring.(the distance between ring and point charge is $r$ and the distance between the centre of the ring and point charge is $d$)
[image]
$$
dE= (k.dq)/r^2
$$
where $dq$ is infinitesimal charge.
$$
dE_x=(k.dq)/r^2cos(\theta)
$$
$$
dE_x=(k.d.dq)/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)}
$$
$$
E_x=∫(k.d.dq)/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)} =(k.d)/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)}∫dq=kdq/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)} 
$$
Finally, we found the electric field of a single ring. However, I am stuck at how to integrate the equation to find the total electric field of the charged tube. How should I integrate and solve the integral.

P.S: I know it is a physics question but there was no answer to this question on [phyics network](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/how-to-find-the-electric-field-of-a-charged-tube) and I thought there would be someone whou could help me on this network.

Comment: It would be helpful to write the variables of each function as not all mathematicians have a physics background. For example, write $\vec{F}(a)=m\vec{a}$ not $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$.